# How can we create a list and use it dynamically in python

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, logic

I want to create a list in python which will be having a variable and its location say a list of 10 values
location from 0 to 9 eg
at location 0 'Abc', 1 'Cde', 2 'Fgh',.... and so on
now I want to use the list values in loop incremented by one

```
list=['Abc','def','ghi'] # Or this may be an excel file with index and one column having different values

i=0 #has list value 'Abc'
while i<=3:
    a=i
    print('List value at'+i+' equals to',List[i])
i=i+1
```

**Input**
data frame

[image]

select List value at index 0 and assign it to an object and then increment index till all the list values.

**Output Required**

```
'List value at 0 equals to Abc'
'List value at 1 equals to def'
'List value at 2 equals to ghi'
'List value at 3 equals to jkl'
'List value at 4 equals to mno'
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output you require.

Comment: You have some errors in your code: 1. `while i<=3` will result in an exception because your list has only three elements (remember: python lists are zero based) 2. You have `list` and `List` 3. Why this `a=i` ? 4. You have the indentation wrong at `i=i+1`

Answer (score 1):

I really didn't get your question, but hope this helps:

### Add element to list

```py
l.append(element)
```

### Get element by position

```py
l[0] # Access element from position 0
```

### Loop through list elements

```py
for i in l:
    print('Item: {}'.format(i))
```

### Loop through list by positions

```py
for i in range(len(l)):
    print('Item: {}'.format(l[i]))
```

**And please, do not name your lists `list`, it shadows the Python `list()` function.**

Comment: You could maybe add slicing to your answer, since there is a `while i<=3:` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**input:**
List.xlsx

[image]

**Process:**

```
k=pd.read_excel('List.xlsx')
m1_list = k.values.tolist()
list = m1_list

i=0
while i < len(list):
    obj= list1[i]
    print(obj)

    i=i+1
```

**output:**

```
'Abc'
'def'
'ghi'
'jkl'
```